# How to import a local module from within pip package?

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I created a pip package; from within this package, I'm trying to import a module from my local filesystem.

Example:
In my pip package `X` I have a function `load_module`:

```py
def load_module(module_name: str):
    imported = __import__(package_name)
```

In the current folder, I have a package called `Y`. If I call X.load_module('Y'), I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Y'
```

Is there any way I can solve the issue? For example, my package needs to load a local module.

I also notice something strange, if I place a breakpoint, for example, with `ipdb`:

```
import ipdb

def load_module(module_name: str):
    ipdb.set_trace()
    imported = __import__(package_name)
```

If I continue the execution after the breakpoint interruption (with `c` in `ipdb`), the import proceeds successfully.

Comment: This, in general, sounds like a bad idea. How would someone downloading said package from `pip` is going to get that local module?

Comment: As for why the import seems to work when using `ipdb`, I suppose it is either modifys the current working dir at runtime, or adds it to `sys.path` under the hood.

Comment: Well the package provides a cli command that reads the modules in the local directory. This is a tool I am developing that is meant to ease development of machine learning modules.

Comment: See if this helps:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/the-implementation-of-import-in-python-importlib

Answer (score 0):

Adding the current directory to `sys.path`, as suggested by [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) solved the issue!
Thank you.

Comment: could you post the final correct solution?